# Find the limit of $\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}$

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

I can not figure out how to find the limit of $\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}$. I know for sure that it's converging.

Comment: The general term is a telescopic term and the given series equals one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $\;\;\displaystyle \frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}=\frac{n+2-1}{(n+2)!}=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}-\frac{1}{(n+2)!}$

Comment: So after your hint I figured out that $s_n=1 - \frac{1}{(n+2)!}$ and this converges to 1. Thanks!

Comment: @Gary Right. Glad to hear you worked it out.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of starting the sum from $0$, we can write

$$S=\sum_{n\ge 2}\frac {n-1}{n!} $$

$$\sum_{n\ge 2}\frac {1}{(n-1)!}-\frac {1}{n!} $$

$$\sum_{n\ge1}\frac {1}{n!}-\sum_{n\ge 2}\frac {1}{n!} $$

$$=1$$